# Collect indexes from list

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

Is there a linq function in c# which enables you to collect IEnumerables from a specific range of indexes?

An example would be

```
        var objectArray = new string[] { "Bill", "Bob", "Joe", "Phil", "Tom", "Paul" };
        var indexArray = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };

        var list = objectArray.Where(SOME_FUNCTION_TO_GET_INDEXES ??).ToList();

        //output would be list:
        //Bob
        //Phil
        //Paul
```

Comment: I've answered assuming that by "random range" you *actually* mean "a specific set obtained from elsewhere, such as in an array". I suggest you edit the question for clarity.

Comment: *Without iterating through the indexes I mean.* iterating through which indexes? Of course you have to iterate through `indexArray`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that they can't iterate, I just meant visibly though code, looping, checking then adding to a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `Select` with your `indexArray` and return the item from `objectArray` via indexing.

```
var list = indexArray.Select(i => objectArray[i]);
```

Note that this works very efficiently for any collection that allows indexing (for example, `Array` and `List<T>`). In the more general case of having an `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`, you wouldn't be able to index directly. In which case you'd need to see Jon's answer. Depending on the sizes of the lists involved, and how many items you need to look up, it might be worth converting your `IEnumerable` to an `Array` or `List` (using `ToArray` for example) first.

Comment: Looks great, thanks.
Thanks also for the quick replies - Looks to be a helpful community.

Answer (score 8):

If the original datasource is already accessible by index, such as for a list or an array, you can just use `indexArray.Select` as Matt showed.

If you've got an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, you can use the `Where` overload which provides the index as well as the value. So:

```
var list = objectArray.Where((value, index) => indexArray.Contains(index))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Now that I've seen this again I remember using it. It didn't stick in my mind because I didn't understand it. It's more clear now, thanks.